# Checking the checked status of a checkbox upon its click

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, checkbox, click

I am trying to test the status of a checkbox upon its click.

My problem is that it always reports as true as it reports the status after the change event has taken place and not before.

Is there anyway I can test before the change.

Current code using jQuery - the checkboxes all of class 'package':

```
$(".package").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        alert($(this).attr("checked"));
    }
});
```

This always returns true even if selecting a checkbox that is not currently checked.

**EDIT :** Ok seems there was some old js interfering with the process, after cleaning that up the click function did indeed work. Thanks all.

Comment: You can use the change event instead: $(".package").change(function() { // value has changed });

Comment: Unfortunately the change event causes the same issues (in FF atleast, atm i've not expanded the testing)

Comment: Hiya, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817735/jquery-using-one-checkbox-to-uncheck-another-programatically cheers!

Comment: Is there a way to see the affected fragment of the actual HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `onchange` event on a checkbox is not [cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1501861/851498) (hello IE! And yes, even with jQuery).

The following works:

```
$('.package').click(function() {
    console.log(this.checked) // There is no need for jQuery here
})
```

Logs 'true' when you check the checkbox, and 'false' when you uncheck it.

And seriously, using `$(this).attr('checked')` or `$(this).is(':checked')` is just jQueryception for nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately still reports true for everything

Comment: I'd like to have more information about your environment then :)

Answer (score 1):

The click event fires before the actual textbox change takes place, you need to subscribe to the change event:

```
$(".package").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        alert($(this).attr("checked"));
    }
});
```

**Edit: Try querying the actual Javascript object itself, should work**

```
$(".package").change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        alert(this.checked);
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately still reports true for everything, even when not previously checked

Comment: @mr12086 check my edit, that works for me :). If it doesn't work for you, could you please show us your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change event instead, this way you are sure the previous checked state is always the oposite of what you read now

```
$(".package").change(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("checked"));
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately still reports true for everything